# Need advice quick: Image not expanding to full height on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress website with event's link on it. Please view the Macedonian version, because most of my event's are not translated to English. Anyway, today I added a new event [(Link to new conference with shortened thumnail)](http://www.cip-cpr.org/portfolio/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%98%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0/) and my thumbnail image doesn't expand to it's full height. As a comparision, this event's thumbnail image is expanded in full height: [(Link to a book event, with a full-height thumb image)](http://www.cip-cpr.org/portfolio/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%98%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80/).

I've been working on this problem for two hours now, and can't seem to locate what blocks the height of my new image thumbnail.

Comment: Code to reproduce the problem needs to be in your question. Linking to a website and asking "what's wrong?" isn't useful for Q+A

Comment: I'm sorry, I know. But, I just can't locate the exact code in my wordpress child-theme, so I was wondering if 'inspect-element' will help you guys?

Comment: It won't - to be useful in the future, I.e. when you've fixed the problem, your question needs to be self-contained. If that's not possible, this isn't the place to ask it

Comment: @BlueBird03, but it is actually extended to it's full height? http://www.cip-cpr.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Plakat-mal-min-1-300x200.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. @nevermind I think I located something: my Portfolio plugin creates a dozen thumb files in image/x-generic and selects a minified version as my thumbnail. I haven't seen something like this up until now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress generates thumbnails at [standard sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes): `medium` being a maximum of 300px wide and 300px tall (although in this case it may be another size created using [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/), as in both examples the image dimensions appear to be set at 300x200, so it's likely that it *should* be being cropped, but it actually seems to be resized to those dimensions proportionally). Either your theme or a plugin is spitting out this size of thumbnail image, and it's being used on the page. This isn't CSS issue - this is Wordpress resizing your images at the point they're uploaded.

Investigate which file/function is outputting these images and set it to a different size (using `the_post_thumbnail('whatever-size-you-want')`). Ideally you'll want to pick a size that does a 'soft' resize without cropping.

Comment: Yes, it's not the CSS. I think I located the problem and it consists of the functions that are being given by the plugin which makes thumbnails for the different images. Thanks for the suggestion.